# Ubuntu on external PCIe SSD - poor read/write performance

Tags: 18.04, usb, ssd, nvme

I bought a PCIe SSD (Toshiba RC100-M22242-240G) and a case for this (FIDECO M.2 NVME SSD Case) and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on that SSD which is connected to my computer via USB3.

However, when I do a quick read/write test via console, I only get very slow speeds for a ssd.

For example with `sudo hdparm -tT --direct /dev/sda` I only get the following read speed:

```
/dev/sda:
Timing O_DIRECT cached reads:    82 MB in  2.02 seconds =  40.67 MB/sec
Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 124 MB in  3.01 seconds =  41.24 MB/sec
```

Comment: Which kind of USB3 connection are you using; a USB-C or a USB-A? If USB-A, what color is the USB socket used on that Toshiba? Have you tried a different cable from the external USB enclosure to the Toshiba?

Comment: @K7AAY well what can I say except thanks for the hint! It was the USB cable. Now I get 390mb/s with the Read test, which seems to be in spec with the claimings of the SSD. Write with dd is at 350mb/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest replacing the cable from the external enclosure to the PC. Pournelle's [Law of Cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Pournelle#Pournelle's_law_of_cables) still holds true today.